# Values-ja-rJP not found

Tags: android, internationalization

I translated my application in the Japanese language. I added regularly the xml file, inside the folder `values-ja-rJP` .
Android studio is regularly set in UTF-8, but when I start my application on my device, the application uses the default language. I need to do something? the problem occurs only with the Japanese language. Thank you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="action_settings">設定</string>
<string name="new_field">新規分野</string>
...
...
</resources>
```

Comment: Does the same problem occur if you use just `res/values-ja`?

Comment: yes, the same problem

Comment: If I insert the file strings.xml translated in Japanase in the default folder (values), it works. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: In my experience I've just used the `values-ja` folder with no problems. How are you you expecting them to be displayed (i.e. are you changing the device locale)?

Comment: ok, solved. thank you

Comment: How did U solved your problem? I have the same folders (values-ja, values-ja-rJP) and no results...